# Settings to enforce Javascript & Typescript coding convention style on VSCode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I am new to VSCode. I am setting up a common environment for
everyone on the team. So that would include following a common coding style/convention.

Are there plugin to achieve/enforce teamwide uniformity for coding style or conventions for Javascript and TypeScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EditorConfig vs. Eslint vs. Prettier: Is it worthwhile to use them all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363647/editorconfig-vs-eslint-vs-prettier-is-it-worthwhile-to-use-them-all) and https://blog.theodo.com/2019/08/why-you-should-use-eslint-prettier-and-editorconfig-together/

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode
Is what everyone is using, simply because it's pretty much perfect.
Add ESLint if you want JS specific help as well.